# Woher stammt die Redewendung "Zwei Dumme, ein Gedanke"?

Tags: etymology, proverb

Eine Google-Suche hat mir dabei nicht viel geholfen, und Lexika zu Redewendungen besitze ich leider nicht.

Weiß jemand mehr zur Herkunft der Floskel **Zwei Dumme, ein Gedanke**?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Es war eigentlich nur ein Kommentar, der die Existenz einer echten Googlesuche in Zweifel ziehen sollte, aber nun gut, jetzt auch als Antwort:

Meine Googlesuche ergibt [diesen Eintrag auf Wikiquote](http://de.wikiquote.org/wiki/Deutsche_Sprichw%C3%B6rter) und das dort verlinkte [Bild](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/c/c5/Wander_DSL_4_0496.jpg) (Eintrag *Zwei Seelen und ein Gedanke*, links oben) aus *Wander: Deutsches Sprichwörter-Lexikon*.

Tl,dr:

> Als *Zwei Seelen und ein Gedanke* in Halms *Sohn der Wildnis*

Answer (score 2):

> Erst im letzten Viertel des 20. Jahrhunderts soll der Spruch entstanden sein. Entstanden ist er vermutlich in der Jugendsprache - und ist bis zum Schluss auch umgangssprachlich geblieben. Schriftlich ist "Zwei Dumme, ein Gedanke" das erste Mal 1988 aufgetaucht. Und zwar im Buch "Caroline unterm Freiheitsbaum" von Brigitte Struzyk. Dort heißt es: „Und erst, als sie den Marktplatz überqueren, bemerken sie, dass ihre Kinder fehlen. Zwei Dumme, ein Gedanke, rufen sie aus einem Munde: 'Röschen! Auguste!“

[Woher kommt – "Zwei Dumme, ein Gedanke"? - Antenne Unna](https://www.antenneunna.de/artikel/woher-kommt-zwei-dumme-ein-gedanke-889525.html)

Comment: Woher weißt Du, dass der Spruch schriftlich erst 1988 aufgetaucht ist?

Comment: Habe ich definitiv um 1970 oder so gehört.